# Controlling DC motor with joystick using Arduino

Tags: arduino-mega, motor

I am working on modifying code to control two DC motors with a joystick using Arduino. The code I have works, but the motor accelerates very rapidly and is difficult to control. I would appreciate any help or pointers to get the motor under control. Here is the code I have so far:

```
const int ledPin = 3; //Led to Arduino pin 3 (PWM)

//Variables
bool started= false;//True: Message is started
bool ended  = false;//True: Message is finished 
char incomingByte ; //Variable to store the incoming byte
char msg[3];    //Message - array from 0 to 2 (3 Drive_Analog_Values -PWM - e.g. 240)
byte index;     //Index of array
bool started1= false;//True: Message is started
bool ended1  = false;//True: Message is finished 
char msg1[3];    //Message - array from 0 to 2 (3 Drive_Analog_Values - PWM - e.g. 240)
byte index1;     //Index of array
bool started2= false;//True: Message is started
bool ended2  = false;//True: Message is finished 
char msg2;
bool started3= false;//True: Message is started
bool ended3  = false;//True: Message is finished 
char msg3;
int Fwd_Drive = 0;
int Rev_Drive = 0;
int Left_Turn = 0;
int Right_Turn = 0;
char Dump = '0';
char Retract = '0';


void setup() {
  
//setup interrupts  
cli();//stop interrupts

//set timer1 interrupt at 1Hz
  TCCR1A = 0;// set entire TCCR1A register to 0
  TCCR1B = 0;// same for TCCR1B
  TCNT1  = 0;//initialize counter value to 0
  // set compare match register for 1hz increments
  OCR1A = 15624;// = (16*10^6) / (1*1024) - 1 (must be <65536)
  // turn on CTC mode
  TCCR1B |= (1 << WGM12);
  // Set CS10 and CS12 bits for 1024 prescaler
  TCCR1B |= (1 << CS12) | (1 << CS10);  
  // enable timer compare interrupt
  TIMSK1 |= (1 << OCIE1A);

 sei();//allow interrupts

  //Start the serial communication
  Serial.begin(9600); //Baud rate must be the same as is on xBee module
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(10, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(6, OUTPUT);
}

ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect){ //timer1 turns off all values every 1 second
   analogWrite(5, 0);
   analogWrite(6, 0);
   analogWrite(9, 0);
   analogWrite(10, 0);
   digitalWrite(2,LOW);
   digitalWrite(4,LOW);
}

void loop() {
  //digitalWrite(13, LOW); //Debug LED
  while (Serial.available()>0){
        //Read the incoming byte
        incomingByte = Serial.read();
        //digitalWrite(13, HIGH);//Debug LED
        //Start the message when the '<' symbol is received
        if(incomingByte == '<'){
            started = true;
            index = 0;
            msg[index] = '\0'; // Throw away any incomplete packet
        }

        //End the message when the '>' symbol is received
        else if(incomingByte == '>'){
            ended = true;
            break; // Done reading - exit from while loop!
        }
        //Read the message!
        else{
            if(index < 4){ // Make sure there is room
                msg[index] = incomingByte; // Add char to array
                index++;
                msg[index] = '\0'; // Add NULL to end
            }
        }
        
        if(incomingByte == '['){
            started2 = true;
            msg2 = '\0';
        }
        else if(incomingByte == ']'){
            ended2 = true;
            break; // Done reading - exit from while loop!
        }
        //Read the message!
        else{
            msg2 = incomingByte;
        }
      if(incomingByte == '{'){
            started3 = true;
            msg3 = '\0';
        }
        else if(incomingByte == '}'){
            ended3 = true;
            break; // Done reading - exit from while loop!
        }
        else{
            msg3 = incomingByte;
        }
    }
 
 if(started && ended){//Driving Logic
        int Drive_Analog_Value = atoi(msg);
        //analogWrite(ledPin, Drive_Analog_Value);//Only for debugging
        //Serial.println(Drive_Analog_Value); //Only for debugging
        if(Drive_Analog_Value>130){
            Rev_Drive = 0;
            Fwd_Drive = map(Drive_Analog_Value, 131, 255, 0, 70);
        }
        else if(Drive_Analog_Value<124){
            Fwd_Drive = 0;
            Rev_Drive = map(Drive_Analog_Value, 0, 123, 70, 0);
        }
        else{
            Fwd_Drive = 0;
            Rev_Drive = 0;
        }
        analogWrite(5, Fwd_Drive);
        analogWrite(6, Rev_Drive);
        index = 0;
        msg[index] = '\0';
        started = false;
        ended = false;
}
```

Comment: that cannot be all of your code ... it does not compile

Comment: please format your code properly the `if`, `else if` and `else` should be at the same indent level

Comment: Have you tried outputting the drive numbers (like `Fwd_Drive`) to Serial and look if they look correct?

Comment: The numbers aren't  correct.  They are way higher than they should be.  Would it be as simple as changing the mapping values?